# how to select the first value and sum other values

Tags: sql

I have this query but I need to adjust it

```
SELECT
    STR_NAME ,
    CNT_ITEM as 'Code',
    TI_NAME as 'Item' ,
    UOM_CODE as UOM,

    sum(CNT_OPEN) as 'ActBeg',    In column i dont need to SUM it i need to get here the value for the first   of the selected date (in this case i need value for 2020-01-01) 
    sum(CNT_RCV )as 'Receiving',
    sum (CNT_TRIN) as 'TransIN',
    sum (ISNULL(CNT_DSD,0) + ISNULL(CNT_PROD,0)) AS 'PROD',
    sum(CNT_VOID ) as 'Void' ,
    sum (CNT_SOLD ) as 'Sales',
    sum (CNT_TROUT ) as 'TransOUT',
    Sum (CNT_CONS) AS 'BatchRMat',
    SUM (ISNULL(CNT_USAGE,0) + CNT_WASTE) as 'WASTE' ,
    sum (CNT_CLOSEC ) as 'TheoEnd' ,
    sum (CNT_CLOSE ) as 'ActEnd',
    sum ((ISNULL(CNT_OPEN,0) - ISNULL(CNT_OPENC,0)) + (ISNULL(CNT_CLOSE,0) - ISNULL(CNT_CLOSEC,0))) 
    AS 'VARIANCE',
    SUM ((ISNULL(CNT_OPEN,0) - ISNULL(CNT_OPENC,0)) + (ISNULL(CNT_CLOSE,0) - ISNULL(CNT_CLOSEC,0)) * 
   CNT_COST) as 'VCost',
    CNT_COST as 'Cost'
FROM
    CR_QC_COUNT LEFT JOIN
    CR_STORE ON STR_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND STR_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND STR_NO = CNT_STR_ID LEFT JOIN
    CR_QC_TRACK ON TI_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND TI_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND TI_ID = CNT_ITEM LEFT JOIN
    CR_QC_UOM ON UOM_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND UOM_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND UOM_ID = TI_PUOM
WHERE
     CNT_COMPANY = 1 AND CNT_BRAND = 1 AND CNT_DOB BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-16' AND CNT_STR_ID IN (41)  and TI_NAME IS NOT NULL  and (CNT_SOLD !=0 or CNT_CONS!=0)
group by 
 STR_NAME,CNT_ITEM ,TI_NAME ,UOM_CODE,CNT_COST
order by 
 STR_NAME , CNT_ITEM
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify the problem - [mcve].

Comment: "First" has no meaning in a relational database unless you also specify something to use to order the data.  Do you mean "first" or do you really mean "minimum"?

Comment: thank you i need the value only the first day in the specified period

Comment: if you like I can share my screen on teams or any other meeting site

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: anybody can connect with me to help me I'm really facing issue

Answer (score -1):

If i have understand the problem correctly, Probably you need below query having co-related sub-query to get the CNT_OPEN value as on `2020-01-01` -

```
SELECT
    STR_NAME ,
    CNT_ITEM as 'Code',
    TI_NAME as 'Item' ,
    UOM_CODE as UOM,

    (SELECT CNT_OPEN
     FROM CR_QC_COUNT
     WHERE CNT_COMPANY = 1
     AND CNT_BRAND = 1 
     AND CNT_DOB = DATE '2020-01-01') as 'ActBeg',    --In column i dont need to SUM it i need to get here the value for the first   of the selected date (in this case i need value for 2020-01-01) 
    sum(CNT_RCV )as 'Receiving',
    sum (CNT_TRIN) as 'TransIN',
    sum (ISNULL(CNT_DSD,0) + ISNULL(CNT_PROD,0)) AS 'PROD',
    sum(CNT_VOID ) as 'Void' ,
    sum (CNT_SOLD ) as 'Sales',
    sum (CNT_TROUT ) as 'TransOUT',
    Sum (CNT_CONS) AS 'BatchRMat',
    SUM (ISNULL(CNT_USAGE,0) + CNT_WASTE) as 'WASTE' ,
    sum (CNT_CLOSEC ) as 'TheoEnd' ,
    sum (CNT_CLOSE ) as 'ActEnd',
    sum ((ISNULL(CNT_OPEN,0) - ISNULL(CNT_OPENC,0)) + (ISNULL(CNT_CLOSE,0) - ISNULL(CNT_CLOSEC,0))) 
    AS 'VARIANCE',
    SUM ((ISNULL(CNT_OPEN,0) - ISNULL(CNT_OPENC,0)) + (ISNULL(CNT_CLOSE,0) - ISNULL(CNT_CLOSEC,0)) * 
   CNT_COST) as 'VCost',
    CNT_COST as 'Cost'
FROM
    CR_QC_COUNT LEFT JOIN
    CR_STORE ON STR_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND STR_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND STR_NO = CNT_STR_ID LEFT JOIN
    CR_QC_TRACK ON TI_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND TI_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND TI_ID = CNT_ITEM LEFT JOIN
    CR_QC_UOM ON UOM_COMPANY = CNT_COMPANY AND UOM_BRAND = CNT_BRAND AND UOM_ID = TI_PUOM
WHERE
     CNT_COMPANY = 1 AND CNT_BRAND = 1 AND CNT_DOB BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-16' AND CNT_STR_ID IN (41)  and TI_NAME IS NOT NULL  and (CNT_SOLD !=0 or CNT_CONS!=0)
group by 
 STR_NAME,CNT_ITEM ,TI_NAME ,UOM_CODE,CNT_COST
order by 
 STR_NAME , CNT_ITEM
```

Since you have not mentioned any alises here so i have just tried to guess the table and columns names here. You may change the conditions as per you requirement.